# How to call custom method of a element in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend

I'm coding a new version of a chrome extision, but got a trouble.

Here's my element code: [Element code](https://github.com/WhaleWatching/pure-newtab/blob/master/newtab.html)

At line 32 I'm tring to call the custom method `willUpdateBackground`, console tells me the method is `undefined`. Code below.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'pure-newtab',
  ready: function() {
    console.dir(this.$.background);
    this.$.background.willUpdateBackground('color', '#333');
    // This line get error, 'willUpdateBackground' is undefined
  }
});
```

The definition

```
Polymer({
  is: 'pure-background',
  ready: function () {
  },
  willUpdateBackground: function(type, imageOrColor) {
    console.log(type);
    console.dir(this);
  }
});
```

But if I store this object, in console I can call the `temp1.willUpdateBackground`, it's weried.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTLgw.png

**Fixed And Problem Happens Again**
I move the custom method call to `attached` callback, elements not ready in `ready` function in some environment.
And after I fixed it, it happens again: in `attached` method, call failed again, and I move it to async call with 100ms delay, problem disappear again. It's not a solid solution, I'm still finding a way out.

```
    this.async(function () {
      this.$['background'].updateBackground('rgba(255,128,0,1)', 'url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)');
    }, 100);
```

Comment: publishes a jsbin to help you. Have you tried using "async function" or the "attached" lifecycle method?

Comment: @FlavioOchoa , it just happened under chrome newtab extension environment. So jsbin can not reproduce it.

Comment: @FlavioOchoa you're right, it can be called on `attached` callback, thanks!

Comment: @FlavioOchoa Oh the problem happens again... In `attached` method, I got undefined call again. I added 100 ms delay and `async` then the element is ready. It's not a solid solution, is there any otherway?

Answer (score 1):

I tried pasting your code into this jsbin and it worked just fine... (I commented your console.dir() and added a couple of console.log() of my own, but that's all I did)
http://jsbin.com/tomewigobu/1/edit?html,console,output

I would suggest you check that your polymer version is updated, that should help.

Comment: It's so weried, there's no `willUpdateBackground` in chrome newtab(Command + T created) environment, just wondering is there any different prototype rules under extension environment?